# Powershell 3.0: Searching specific file names and sending the names to a .txt file

Tags: powershell

Here is  my code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'R:\Source\Path' |
ForEach-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*condition*' } > 'R:\Destination\Path\File.txt'
```

The code is working to some extent. Except instead of copying the names of the files to the destination, it is instead writing either true or false into the text file depending on the status of the condition. So where I would expect a .txt file list of names, instead I have something that looks like:

```
True
True
False
True
False
False
```

...and so on ...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You are redirecting the _output of your commands_ to file. `$_.Name -notlike '*condition*'` returns a boolean which is why you see what you do. Change it to where-object instead of foreach-object

Comment: After I posted this question I tested using where-object instead and it worked! Thanks so much for the reply, though, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter your output, use `Where-Object` instead of `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*.zip"} > output.txt
```

To get the full path to the file and nothing else, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*.zip"} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName > output.txt
```

or change the logic inside your original ForEach-Object scriptblock to actually *act* on the result of `-notlike`:

```
Get-ChildItem |ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Name -notlike "*.zip"){
        $_.FullName
    }
} > output.txt
```

Comment: I'm very new to powershell, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is the difference between .Name and .FullName?

Comment: @GalenH Name of the file and full file path.

Comment: @GalenH `Get-ChildItem` returns objects of the type `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` - they both have a `Name` and a `FullName` property. `Name` is the name of the file/directory - `FullName` is the full filesystem path to the file/directory

Comment: Oh, okay -- that's cool! Last question, when I run the Where-Object code I end up with a text file that contains mode, last write time, length, and name. Is there another filter I can implement that will only pass the name information?

Comment: @GalenH Already shown that with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`. If you want to avoid extra spacing, use `| Out-File ` instead of `>`